# How to access a QLabel created in QtCreator Designer?

Tags: qt, opencv, qt-creator

I created a few `QLabel` in my MainWindow using Qt Creator and opencv, but I have this error :

> error: 'ui' was not declared in this scope

in the function `filter_image()`. I want to use label to show an image before and after doing some processing.

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include<QImage>
#include<QLabel>

static QImage IplImage2QImage(const IplImage *iplImage) {
    int height = iplImage->height;
    int width = iplImage->width;
    if  (iplImage->depth == IPL_DEPTH_8U && iplImage->nChannels == 3)
    {
        const uchar *qImageBuffer = (const uchar*)iplImage->imageData;
        QImage img(qImageBuffer, width, height, QImage::Format_RGB888);
        return img.rgbSwapped();
    }
    else if  (iplImage->depth == IPL_DEPTH_8U && iplImage->nChannels == 1)
    {
        const uchar *qImageBuffer = (const uchar*)iplImage->imageData;
        QImage img(qImageBuffer, width, height, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
        QVector<QRgb> colorTable;
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
            colorTable.push_back(qRgb(i, i, i));
        }
        img.setColorTable(colorTable);
        return img;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Image cannot be converted.";
        return QImage();
    }
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent *e)
{
    QMainWindow::changeEvent(e);
    switch (e->type()) {
    case QEvent::LanguageChange:
        ui->retranslateUi(this);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void filter_image(IplImage* img) {
    IplImage* roi = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 3);
    cvCvtColor( img, roi, CV_RGB2GRAY );
    cvSmooth(img,roi,CV_BLUR, 5, 0, 0, 0);
    cvThreshold(roi,roi,100,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    IplImage *img_de = cvCloneImage(roi);
    QImage qt_i = IplImage2QImage(img_de);
    QLabel label_2;
    // display on label
    ui->label_2->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qt_i));//error line
    // resize the label to fit the image
    ui->label_2->resize(ui->label_2->pixmap()->size());
    label_2.show();
}

void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered() {
    IplImage *frame = cvLoadImage(
        QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, 
                                     "Ouvrir un fichier", 
                                     "/../../Fichiers Image", 
                                     "Image (*.jpg *.bmp *.jpeg)")
                                     .toStdString().c_str(),3);
    IplImage *img_des = cvCloneImage(frame);
    QImage qt_im = IplImage2QImage(img_des);
    QLabel label;
    // display on label
    ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qt_im));
    // resize the label to fit the image
    ui->label->resize(ui->label->pixmap()->size());
    label.show();
    filter_image(frame);
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

public:    
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

protected:
    void changeEvent(QEvent *e);

public:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

public slots:
    void on_actionOpen_triggered();    
};
```

ui_mainwindow.h

```
#include <QtCore/QVariant>

#include <QtGui/QAction>

#include <QtGui/QApplication>

#include <QtGui/QButtonGroup>

#include <QtGui/QHeaderView>

#include <QtGui/QLabel>

#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>

#include <QtGui/QMenu>

#include <QtGui/QMenuBar>

#include <QtGui/QStatusBar>

#include <QtGui/QToolBar>

#include <QtGui/QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_MainWindow{


public:
QAction *actionOpen;
QWidget *centralWidget;
QLabel *label;
QLabel *label_2;
QMenuBar *menuBar;
QMenu *menuFile;
QToolBar *mainToolBar;
QStatusBar *statusBar;

void setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
{
    if (MainWindow->objectName().isEmpty())
        MainWindow->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("MainWindow"));
    MainWindow->resize(600, 400);
    actionOpen = new QAction(MainWindow);
    actionOpen->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("actionOpen"));
    centralWidget = new QWidget(MainWindow);
    centralWidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("centralWidget"));
    label = new QLabel(centralWidget);
    label->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("label"));
    label->setGeometry(QRect(290, 30, 271, 301));
    label_2 = new QLabel(centralWidget);
    label_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("label_2"));
    label_2->setGeometry(QRect(20, 20, 281, 331));
    MainWindow->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
    menuBar = new QMenuBar(MainWindow);
    menuBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("menuBar"));
    menuBar->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 600, 21));
    menuFile = new QMenu(menuBar);
    menuFile->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("menuFile"));
    MainWindow->setMenuBar(menuBar);
    mainToolBar = new QToolBar(MainWindow);
    mainToolBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("mainToolBar"));
    MainWindow->addToolBar(Qt::TopToolBarArea, mainToolBar);
    statusBar = new QStatusBar(MainWindow);
    statusBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("statusBar"));
    MainWindow->setStatusBar(statusBar);

    menuBar->addAction(menuFile->menuAction());
    menuFile->addAction(actionOpen);

    retranslateUi(MainWindow);

    QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(MainWindow);
} // setupUi

void retranslateUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
{
    MainWindow->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
    actionOpen->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "Open", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
    label->setText(QString());
    label_2->setText(QString());
    menuFile->setTitle(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "File", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
} // retranslateUi};



namespace Ui {
class MainWindow: public Ui_MainWindow {};

} // namespace Ui
```

Comment: What line is causing the error? Also, formatting the code better would help a lot.

Comment: C:/Users/nadia/Desktop/Qt_app/app/mainwindow.cpp:108: error: 'ui' was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 3):

The method `filter_image`, which is where the error is occurring, is not a class method of `MainWindow`, so it doesn't have access to `MainWindow`'s members (including `ui`).

You can do a couple of things: if it makes sense, make it part of the `MainWindow` class. Alternatively, you can pass the ui as a parameter:

```
void filter_image(Ui::MainWindow* ui, /*other params*/){...}
```

Also, you are making a local variable `label_2` rather than taking the one from the gui.

Comment: i have this error C:/Users/nadia/Desktop/Qt_app/app/mainwindow.cpp:142: error: cannot convert 'IplImage*' to 'Ui::MainWindow*' for argument '1' to 'void filter_image(Ui::MainWindow*, IplImage*)'

Comment: Well yeah - call it with filter_image(ui,IplImage*), since now it takes two parameters.

Comment: Also note that this is just a hack so you can test it out. What would be smarter is to return a `QImage` from the filter_image method, so that function no longer needs to know about the ui at all. Call it from the MainWindow, get back the image, and *then* display it.

Comment: I take it that it is successfully compiling, then. Which means you're making progress. Have you tried printing debug messages to figure out *where* it is crashing? Also, as I noted in the answer, your local `QLabel label` may be a source of problems - it isn't part of the gui, after all, it's just a local variable.

Comment: when i try to add Ui::MainWindow* ui it work but i have an other small window

Comment: it's ok it doesn't crach but i have other window

Comment: @tmpeace sorry i dont undrestand you